# How to Solve or LinearSolve $A = I$ matrix equation?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'd like to solve this equation for $A = B$ where $B = I$, which represents 3 systems of 3 linear equations, for $a, b, c, d, e, f$, without writing `LinearSolve` 3 times. What is a simple way to accomplish this?

Input:

```
   A = {
   {a + b, -a + b, a + 2 b}, 
   {c + d, -c + d, c + 2 d}, 
   {e + f, -e + f, e + 2 b}
   };
MatrixForm[A]
B = IdentityMatrix[3]
(*want to solve A == B, but probably wrong...*)
M = LinearSolve[A, IdentityMatrix[3]]
MatrixForm[M]
```

Comment: So you want to invert `A` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks If `A == I` then also `A^-1 == I`. Thus he just wants to find `a,b,c,d,e,f`rather than `A^-1`.

Comment: @T.Webster Could you explain what you'd expected from an answer,  if existing ones were not satisfactory ?

Comment: @Artes Sorry I have been away and thanks for your answer.

Comment: The question related to finding the left inverse of some matrix $A$. But a solution I found from my linear algebra course is to use Gaussian elim. (RowReduce) with the augmented matrix $[A I]$.

Comment: @T.Webster You are welcome. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says : `LinearSolve[m,b]` finds an `x` which solves the matrix equation `m.x == b`, i.e. in your case it finds `x` such that `A.x == B` (`Dot[A,x] == B`). However your task is to find `A`  solving an adequate system of `9 linear equations` for 6 variables `a,b,c,d,e,f` knowing that `B` is an `IdentityMatrix`. You are trying to solve an overdetermined system of linear equations and there could exist any solutions only if certain compatibility conditions were satisfied.

For your task use simply `Solve` :

```
Solve[A == B, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

or

```
Reduce[A == B, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

This means that there are no solutions, i.e. the above equation is contradictory.
You could use `Variables[A]` instead of specifying variables `{a, b, c, d, e, f}`.

Consider a different matrix equation where we have `4` unknowns and `4` independent equations e.g. :

```
A1 = {{a + b, a - 2 b}, {a - c, c + d}};
Solve[ A1 == IdentityMatrix[2], {a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 2/3, b -> 1/3, c -> 2/3, d -> 1/3}}
> ```

i.e. there is only one solution.

**Edit**

`Inverse[A]` could be a solution assuming that  you wanted  `x` in the matrix equation `A.x == IdentityMatrix[3]` when `A` was given. There exists an inverse matrix to  `A` under this condition :

```
Det[ A] != 0
```

i.e.

```
-4 b^2 c + 4 a b d + 4 b c f - 4 a d f != 0
```

Neither `A` exists  nor this assumption can be satisfied when `A` is defined as in your question and `B` is an identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Inverse` to invert a matrix :

```
bigA = {{a + b, -a + b, a + 2 b}, {c + d, -c + d, c + 2 d}, {e + f, -e + f, e + 2 b}};

bigM=Inverse[bigA]
```