# LinearSolve symbolic equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to use mathematica to solve the following system of equation, but I can not for the life of me get it to work.  I have the following:

```
Stiffness = ((Y*A)/L )*{{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 
 2, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}} // MatrixForm

Displacements = {{0}, {a}, {b}, {0}} // MatrixForm

Force = {{x}, {(7*L^3 )/162}, {(10*L^3)/81}, {y}} // MatrixForm
```

I need to solve:

```
Stiffness * Displacements = Force
```

When I use LinearSolve it just spits back the input command.  I need to solve for a, b, x, and y.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I find your question a duplicate of at least a few another ones, e.g. [How to Solve or LinearSolve A=I matrix equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10359/how-to-solve-or-linearsolve-a-i-matrix-equation). In any case you can do: `Solve[ Stiffness[[1]].Displacements[[1]] == Force[[1]], {a, b, x, y}]` yielding `{{a -> (17 L^4)/(243 A Y), b -> (47 L^4)/(486 A Y), x -> -((17 L^3)/243), y -> -((47 L^3)/486)}}`. Incorrect usage: `*` and `=`, use `.` and `==` respectively i.e. (`Dot` and `Equal`) instead of `Times` and `Set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the code: `MatrixForm` is just for display, you have extra brackets in the lists, use dot `.` for matrix multiplication, double equals `==` to define an equation, and you need to ask it to solve for the desired variables:

```
Stiffness = ((Y*A)/L)*{{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 2, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1}};
Displacements = {0, a, b, 0};
Force = {x, (7*L^3)/162, (10*L^3)/81, y};
Solve[Stiffness.Displacements == Force, {a, b, x, y}]

{{a -> (17 L^4)/(243 A Y), b -> (47 L^4)/(486 A Y), 
  x -> -((17 L^3)/243), y -> -((47 L^3)/486)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question on both sites, I forgot to delete the one over on StackOverflow after I posted here. I figured this place was more fitting.